# Can't get attributes of AWS SQS queue using Java & TestContainers

Tags: java, amazon-sqs, testcontainers, localstack

The code below reproduces a problem I'm seeing in some of our tests. We

- start up a test container
- create an SQS client
- use that client to create a queue
- attempt to look up the queue ARN

The queue creation appears to be successful, and returns this URL:

`http://sqs.us-east-1.localhost:4566/000000000000/my-queue`

But, attempting to query the queue attributes results in:

`java.net.UnknownHostException: sqs.us-east-1.localhost`

```
public class Main {

    private static final LocalStackContainer localStack =
            new LocalStackContainer(DockerImageName.parse(
                    "localstack/localstack:3.1")).withServices(SQS);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        localStack.start();

        // create SQS client
        AmazonSQSAsync sqs = AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withEndpointConfiguration(new EndpointConfiguration(
                        localStack.getEndpointOverride(SQS).toString(),
                        localStack.getRegion()))
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
                        new BasicAWSCredentials(
                                localStack.getAccessKey(),
                                localStack.getSecretKey())))
                .build();

        // create a new queue
        String url = sqs.createQueue("my-queue").getQueueUrl();

        // get ARN of new queue 
        String arn = sqs.getQueueAttributes(url, List.of("QueueArn"))
                .getAttributes().get("QueueArn");
    }
}
```

The code above is part of maven project with these (and only these) dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sqs</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.646</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
    <artifactId>localstack</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.4</version>
</dependency>
```

I can't figure out why `createQueue()` works, but `getQueueAttributes()` doesn't. What am I doing wrong here?

[In the 'real' code I can't change the `aws-java-sdk-sqs` version, but I'm happy to change the TestContainers and LocalStack versions if that would help]

Update: fixed by Thrau's suggestion (see below). Need to use the latest LocalStack and set `SQS_ENDPOINT_STRATEGY` to `dynamic`:

```
LocalStackContainer localStack =
  new LocalStackContainer(DockerImageName.parse("localstack/localstack:latest"))
    .withEnv("SQS_ENDPOINT_STRATEGY", "dynamic")
    .withServices(SQS);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple fix would be to use the `path` strategy for generating SQS Queue URLs, by adding

```java
    private static final LocalStackContainer localStack =
            new LocalStackContainer(DockerImageName.parse("localstack/localstack:3.1"))
        .withServices(SQS)
        .withEnv("SQS_ENDPOINT_STRATEGY", "path");
```

**Explanation**: In LocalStack, there are different ways how resource URLs like SQS Queue URLs are generated. For SQS, they are documented [here](https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/aws/sqs/#queue-urls).

It seems your setup uses the `standard` strategy, where the Queue URL pattern is `sqs.<region>.localhost.localstack.cloud:4566/<account_id>/<queue_name>`. Just that it seems instead of `localhost.localstack.cloud`, you're getting only `localhost`, which leads to invalid URLs. This can be because you're also somehow setting [`LOCALSTACK_HOST`](https://docs.localstack.cloud/references/configuration/#core) to `localhost` (perhaps this is an issue with Testcontainers?). With the `path` strategy, you will get a valid URL, even if you use `localhost` as the default localstack hostname.

Comment: Thanks this helped, but I still needed to edit the port in the url to use the external container port. e.g. I have to convert: http://localhost:4566/queue/us-east-1/000000000000/my-queue to something like http://localhost:37699/queue/us-east-1/000000000000/my-queue, where 37699 is the external port mapped to 4566. Surely, I shouldn't need to do this?

Comment: Generally we don't recommend using a random port for localstack, as it causes the issues you are running into right now. You can look into the `dynamic` endpoint strategy for SQS. See the discussion here https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/9753 i